# How to properly update a State var from a separate view in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, photosui

I have a `WineInfoView` that displays an array of images of a particular wine. The last "image" in the horizontal scroll is a blank image that when tapped on shows the users camera roll and allows them to add a new image.

When I test it out in `HorizontalImageScrollView()` i correctly places the new image before the last "image" but the changes are visible when tested in ``WineInfoView``` or running the app on my device.

Here is the code for the two views:

**WineInfoView**

```
struct WineInfoView: View {
    //ADD MODEL HERE
    @State var wine: Wine
    
    var body: some View {
        HorizontalImageScrollView(wine: $wine)         
    }
}
```

**Horizontal Image Scroll:**

```
struct HorizontalImageScrollView: View {
    @Binding var wine: Wine
    
    //For selecting / adding phtotos
    @State var photoPickerPresented: Bool = false
    @State var cameraPresente: Bool = false
    @State private var selectedItem: PhotosPickerItem?
    @State var image: UIImage?
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, content: {
            //parse through images that exist
            HStack {
                ForEach(wine.images, id: \.self) { image in
                    Image(uiImage: image)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .frame(width: 175, height: 250)
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0))
                        .padding()
                }
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                ///// PHOTO PICKER
                //empty "Image" to add more pictures
                PhotosPicker(selection: $selectedItem, label: {
                    ZStack {
                        Color(uiColor: UIColor(rgb: 0xEDEDE9))
                            .frame(width: 175, height: 250)
                            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0))
                            .padding([.leading,.trailing])
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                    }
                })
                .onChange(of: selectedItem) {
                    Task {
                        if let data = try? await selectedItem?.loadTransferable(type: Data.self) {
                            image = UIImage(data: data)
                            //add image to local object
                            wine.images.append(image!)
                            //update record in DB
                            updateWineRecordPhotos(wine.images)
                        } else {
                            print("Failed to load the image")
                        }
                    }
                }
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            }
            
        })
    }
}
```

Can someone explain why the changes are not being displayed in the `WineInfoView`

**Edit**

I have two use cases for this Image scroll:

1. Displaying already existing images in a `WineInfoView` which is display by selecting a wine from a list.
2. Allowing users to add images to an empty wine object while adding a new wine when they press the button with the plus sign.

Here is the prevalent code:

**MyListView**

```
struct MyListView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model : Model
    @State private var newWineViewVisible: Bool = false
    
    init(model: Model) {
        self.model = model
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        //Header
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text ("vino")
                        .font(.custom("DMSerifDisplay-Regular", size: 24))
                        .padding(.leading, 50)
                    
                    Spacer()
                    //user pfp : on tap -> account managment
                    Button(action: {
                        newWineViewVisible = true
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                            .resizable()
                    })
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                    .padding()
                }
                List {
                    ForEach($model.activeUser.wines, id: \.id) { wine in
                        NavigationLink(destination: WineInfoView(wine: wine), label: {
                            WineListView(wine: wine.wrappedValue)
                                .frame(height: 100)
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $newWineViewVisible, onDismiss: {
                newWineViewVisible = false
            }, content: {
                NewWineView(model: model)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

**NewWineView**

```
struct NewWineView: View {
    @State private var wine: Wine = Wine()
    
    //MARK: body
    var body: some View {
        HorizontalImageScrollView(wine: $wine)
    }
}
```

**Wine class**
Note: This needs to stay a class in order to run the async init from a CKRecord

```
class Wine: Identifiable {
    
    var type: String
    var vintage: String
    var vineyard: Vineyard
    var images: [UIImage]
    var cloudID: String
    var recordID: CKRecord.ID
    let id: UUID = UUID()//to make wine conform to identifiable
    
    init(_ type: String,_ vintage: String,_ vineyard: Vineyard,_ images: [UIImage] = [],_ cloudID: String = "",_ recordID: CKRecord.ID = CKRecord(recordType: "Wine").recordID) {
        self.type = type
        self.vintage = vintage
        self.vineyard = vineyard
        self.images = images
        self.cloudID = cloudID
        self.recordID = recordID
    }
    
    init() {
        self.type = ""
        self.vintage = ""
        self.vineyard = Vineyard()
        self.images = []
        let record = CKRecord(recordType: "Wine")
        self.cloudID = record.recordID.recordName
        self.recordID = record.recordID
    }
    
    init(_ ckrecord: CKRecord) async throws {
        self.type = ckrecord["Type"] as! String
        self.vintage = ckrecord["Vintage"] as! String
        self.cloudID = ckrecord.recordID.recordName
        self.recordID = ckrecord.recordID
        
        //Process Photos
        let imageAssets = ckrecord["Pictures"] as! [CKAsset]
        var uiImages: [UIImage] = []
        var imageData = Data()
        for asset in imageAssets {
            do {
                imageData = try Data(contentsOf: asset.fileURL!)
                uiImages.append(UIImage(data: imageData)!)
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        self.images = uiImages
        
        //create vineyard from record
        //set as empty in order to use self in async
        self.vineyard = Vineyard()
        let vineyardRef = ckrecord["Vineyard"] as! CKRecord.Reference
        let cloudDB = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
        Task {
            do {
                let fetchedRecord = try await cloudDB.record(for: vineyardRef.recordID)
                // Handle the fetched record
                self.vineyard = Vineyard(fetchedRecord)
            } catch {
                print("Error fetching record: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the current code for `HorizontalImageScrollView` shown the use case for wine info view is satisfied but when adding images to an empty wine object, `Wine()`, Images only appear after a second image is selected.

This should provide a comprehensive overview of the problem if extra code is needed please let me know.

Comment: State should Always be private

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instantiate a wine object in your `WineInfoView`,
such as: `@State private var wine: Wine = Wine(.... ,images: [])` so that images can be added to and displayed in `WineInfoView`.

Also avoid using forced unwrapping `!`, eg: `wine.images.append(image!)`, see the code update.

Here is my test code that works well for me when I select a photo, not a video etc...

On MacOS 14.3, using Xcode 15.2, tested on real ios 17 devices (not Previews) and macCatalyst. It could be different on older systems.

```
// for testing
struct Wine: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var images: [UIImage]
    // ....
}

struct WineInfoView: View {
    @State private var wine: Wine = Wine(name: "Chateau Cardboard", images: []) // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        HorizontalImageScrollView(wine: $wine)
    }
}

struct HorizontalImageScrollView: View {
    @Binding var wine: Wine
    
    //For selecting / adding phtotos
    @State var photoPickerPresented: Bool = false
    @State var cameraPresente: Bool = false
    @State private var selectedItem: PhotosPickerItem?
    @State var image: UIImage?  // <--- not used
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, content: {
            //parse through images that exist
            HStack {
                ForEach(wine.images, id: \.self) { image in
                    Image(uiImage: image)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .frame(width: 175, height: 250)
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0))
                        .padding()
                }
                //empty "Image" to add more pictures
                PhotosPicker(selection: $selectedItem, label: {
                    ZStack {
                        Color(uiColor: .lightGray)
                            .frame(width: 175, height: 250)
                            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0))
                            .padding([.leading,.trailing])
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                    }
                })
                .onChange(of: selectedItem) {
                    Task {
                        if let data = try? await selectedItem?.loadTransferable(type: Data.self),
                            let img = UIImage(data: data) {
                            image = img
                            //add image to local object
                            wine.images.append(img)
                            //update record in DB
                            // updateWineRecordPhotos(wine.images) // for testing
                        } else {
                            print("----> Failed to load the image")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

EDIT-1:

if you are passing the `wine` object from a parent view into `WineInfoView`,
then use a `Binding`, such as:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var wine: Wine = Wine(name: "Chateau Cardboard", images: []) // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        WineInfoView(wine: $wine) // <--- here
    }
}

struct WineInfoView: View {
    @Binding var wine: Wine // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        HorizontalImageScrollView(wine: $wine)
    }
}

struct HorizontalImageScrollView: View {
    @Binding var wine: Wine  // <--- here
    // .....
```

EDIT-2:  removed

EDIT-3:

In response to your new code, here is a fully working example code that works well for me.

The important parts are to use `struct Wine`, `struct Vineyard` etc...
for the contituents of the `model`. Since you don't want to show the code for `model`, I created a `class Model: ObservableObject` that works well in my tests.
This `model` is passed to other views using the `@EnvironmentObject var model: Model`.

The example code uses `@Binding var wine: Wine` to allow particular `wine` object to
be changed in the views, eg adding images.

See also: [monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = Model()  // <--- here, must have only one
    
    var body: some View {
        MyListView()
            .environmentObject(model) // <--- here
    }
}

struct HorizontalImageScrollView: View {
    @Binding var wine: Wine  // <--- here
    
    //For selecting / adding phtotos
    @State var photoPickerPresented: Bool = false
    @State var cameraPresente: Bool = false
    @State private var selectedItem: PhotosPickerItem?
    @State var image: UIImage?
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, content: {
            //parse through images that exist
            HStack {
                ForEach(wine.images, id: \.self) { image in
                    Image(uiImage: image)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .frame(width: 175, height: 250)
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0))
                        .padding()
                }

                PhotosPicker(selection: $selectedItem, label: {
                    ZStack {
                        Color.pink
                            .frame(width: 175, height: 250)
                            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0))
                            .padding([.leading,.trailing])
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                    }
                })
                .onChange(of: selectedItem) {
                    Task {
                        if let data = try? await selectedItem?.loadTransferable(type: Data.self) {
                            image = UIImage(data: data)
                            //add image to local object
                            wine.images.append(image!)
                            //update record in DB
                          //  updateWineRecordPhotos(wine.images)
                        } else {
                            print("Failed to load the image")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
}

struct MyListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model  // <--- here
    
    @State private var newWineViewVisible: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        //Header
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text ("vino")
                        .font(.custom("DMSerifDisplay-Regular", size: 24))
                        .padding(.leading, 50)
                    
                    Spacer()
                    //user pfp : on tap -> account managment
                    Button(action: {
                        newWineViewVisible = true
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                            .resizable()
                    })
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                    .padding()
                }
                
                // <---
                List {
                    ForEach($model.activeUser.wines) { $wine in
                        NavigationLink(destination: WineInfoView(wine: $wine)) {
                            WineListView(wine: wine).frame(height: 100)
                        }
                    }
                }
                // <---
                
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $newWineViewVisible) {
                NewWineView()
                    .environmentObject(model) // <--- here
            }
        }
    }
}

struct NewWineView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model  // <--- here
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss  // <--- here
    
    @State private var newWine = Wine()
    
    var body: some View {
        HorizontalImageScrollView(wine: $newWine)
        Button("Save new wine") {
            model.activeUser.wines.append(newWine)
            dismiss()
        }.buttonStyle(.bordered)
    }
}

struct WineListView: View {
    var wine: Wine
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(wine.type)
            Text(wine.vintage)
            // ....other
        }
    }
}

struct WineInfoView: View {
    @Binding var wine: Wine  // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        HorizontalImageScrollView(wine: $wine)
    }
}

struct Wine: Identifiable {  // <--- here
    
    var type: String
    var vintage: String
    var vineyard: Vineyard
    var images: [UIImage]
    var cloudID: String
    var recordID: CKRecord.ID
    let id: UUID = UUID()//to make wine conform to identifiable
    
    init(_ type: String,_ vintage: String,_ vineyard: Vineyard,_ images: [UIImage] = [],_ cloudID: String = "",_ recordID: CKRecord.ID = CKRecord(recordType: "Wine").recordID) {
        self.type = type
        self.vintage = vintage
        self.vineyard = vineyard
        self.images = images
        self.cloudID = cloudID
        self.recordID = recordID
    }
    
    init() {
        self.type = "new wine type"
        self.vintage = String(Int.random(in: 1900...2023)) // for testing
        self.vineyard = Vineyard()
        self.images = []
        let record = CKRecord(recordType: "Wine")
        self.cloudID = record.recordID.recordName
        self.recordID = record.recordID
    }
    
    init(_ ckrecord: CKRecord) async throws {
        self.type = ckrecord["Type"] as! String
        self.vintage = ckrecord["Vintage"] as! String
        self.cloudID = ckrecord.recordID.recordName
        self.recordID = ckrecord.recordID
        
        //Process Photos
        let imageAssets = ckrecord["Pictures"] as! [CKAsset]
        var uiImages: [UIImage] = []
        var imageData = Data()
        for asset in imageAssets {
            do {
                imageData = try Data(contentsOf: asset.fileURL!)
                uiImages.append(UIImage(data: imageData)!)
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        self.images = uiImages
        
        //create vineyard from record
        //set as empty in order to use self in async
        self.vineyard = Vineyard()
        if let fetchedRecord = await getRecord(ckrecord) {  // <--- here
            self.vineyard.record = fetchedRecord
        }
    }
    
    // --- here, untested
    func getRecord(_ ckrecord: CKRecord) async -> CKRecord? {
        let vineyardRef = ckrecord["Vineyard"] as! CKRecord.Reference
        let cloudDB = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
        let fetchedRecord = Task { () -> CKRecord in
            do {
                return try await cloudDB.record(for: vineyardRef.recordID)
            } catch {
                print("Error fetching record: \(error)")
            }
            throw CKError(.badContainer)
        }
        let result = await fetchedRecord.result
        do {
             return try result.get()
         } catch {
             print("Unable to fetch the record \(error)")
         }
        return nil
    }
    
}

class Model: ObservableObject {  // <--- here
    
    @Published var activeUser: User = User()
    // ...

}

struct Vineyard: Identifiable {  // <--- here
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var record: CKRecord
    // ....
    
    init() { 
        self.name = "Chateau"
        self.record = CKRecord(recordType: "Vineyard")
    }
    
    init(_ ckrecord: CKRecord) {
        self.name = "Chateau"
        self.record = ckrecord
    }
}

struct User: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    
    var name: String = "no name"
    var wines: [Wine] = []
    // ....
}
```

Comment: This answer worked prefectly for when the wine already had images, but when using it for creating a new wine and passing a wine with an empty array of images it only showed the first image selected after a second image was selected. Is there any reason for that?

Comment: Don't really understand what you are asking here. In the code I show,
 the wine object has no images to start with.
 `@State private var wine: Wine = Wine(name: "Chateau Cardboard", images: [])`.
When I add a selected image (from PhotosPicker) it is appended to the array `wine.images.append(img)`.
 Edit your question with the code you are using showing the relevant code where you try to create a new wine object and add the images.

Comment: This is because you are using a `class Wine: ...`, use `struct Wine: ...` instead, like in my answer.
 Note there is no need for a `init()`, it is generated automatically for `structs`.

Comment: updated my answer again using the `Observation framework`, see `EDIT-2`

Comment: The environment tag worked great for the new wine view but is giving me issues for calling it inside a list, I added the new code. Is the use cases different enough to warrant a separate view implementation?

Comment: Not clear what you are doing from your disjointed code.
`wine` object is from a `model`, this changes everything.
 Show the code for your `model` class and how you declare it inside the view
and pass it to other views. My guess is, use a `struct Wine`, like in my first option and EDIT-1.
 Do not use `.environment(wine)` (specially inside a ForEach loop) if you are not using the `Observation` framework (ie if no `@Observable class Wine`). Note, I don't understand what you mean `Using Image Scroll View when creating new Wine`.

Comment: Updated my answer with EDIT-3, a fully working example that you can use to build on. Let me know if this code does not work for you.